# Get exponent of a BigDecimal

Tags: java, clojure, bigdecimal

I want to get the exponent of a BigDecimal.

```
`1M` (`1E0M`)      -> `0`
`10M` (`1E1M`)     -> `1`
`11M` (`1.1E1M`)   -> `1`
`1E2M`             -> `2`
`1.0E2M`           -> `2`
`100M` (`1.00E2M`) -> `2`
```

[`scale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#scale%28%29), at least by itself, is not what I need. I would really rather not have to use `.toPlainString` and hack something around that.

I'm a little surprised that the exponent I want isn't part of the internal representation of a BigDecimal.

I'm using BigDecimal from Clojure, but any logic that works for Java is welcome too.

Comment: If you `stripTrailingZeros` first, `scale` should give you what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defn exp<-bigdec
  "Returns the exponent, b, from a BigDecimal in the form a * 10 ^ b."
  [x]
  (- (.precision x) (.scale x) 1))
```

Comment: i.e. `x.precision() - x.scale() - 1` in Java; this seems to work on all the cases I tried.